# Logout routing using OAuth and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm using OAuth 2 gem to authenticate via google and facebook. 
I need to do logout from google and facebook when I logout from my application. In OA documentation said to:

```
devise_scope :user do
delete 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
end
```

Add this to routes.rb. I did it so, my routs rb now looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'callbacks' }
  devise_scope :user do
    delete 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  end
```

When I add this line, i got an error when i try to rails s my application:

> /Users/damirik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:507:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'destroy_user_session'  (ArgumentError)
>   You may have defined two routes with the same name using the`:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.

I really dont understand how to fix it. Help please

Comment: Have you checked if everything looks all right in `rake routes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [devise_for](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3Adevise_for) method documentation, I can see that it already adds the exact `delete 'sign_out'` route, which makes it redundant.

This should be enough to make your code work.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'callbacks' }
end
```